# Indexing in python quadtree

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, quadtree

I have a set of points with their coordinates (latitudes, longigutes), and I also have a region (a box). All the points are inside the box.
Now I want to distribute the points into small cells (rectangles) considering the density of points. Basically, a cell containing many points should be subdivided into smaller ones, while keeping larger cells with small number of points.

I have check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058586/python-quadtree-index-returning-nodes), which has almost the same problem with me but I couldn't find a good answer. I think I should use a quad tree, but all implementations I found doesn't provide that.

For example, [this](https://github.com/karimbahgat/Pyqtree) library allows making a tree associated with a box, and then we can insert boxes as follows:

```
spindex = Index(bbox=(0, 0, 100, 100))
for item in items:
    spindex.insert(item, item.bbox)
```

But it doens't allow inserting points. Moreover, I'll need to get the IDs of cells (or names), and check if a point belongs to a given cell.

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartquadtree) is another lib I found. It does allow inserting points, but it doens't give me the cell's ID (or name), so I cannot check if a point belongs to a certain cell. Notice that the tree should do the decomposition automatically.

Could you please suggest me a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Got a downvote without understanding :-|

Comment: Like the answer you linked suggests, it's usually easier to use something like postgis. But asking for library suggestions is off-topic on SO, as you probably know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I ended up using Google's [s2-geometry-library](https://github.com/micolous/s2-geometry-library) with Python wrapper. In fact, each cell created by this lib is not a rectangle (it's a projection), but it satisfies my need. The lib already divided the earth surface into cells at different levels (quad tree). Given an point (lat,lng), I can easily get a corresponding cell at leaf level. From these leaf nodes, I go up and merge cells based on what I need (number of points in a cell).
[This](http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/) tutorial explains everything in details.

Here is my result:
[image]